# por que esta funcion split funciona al concatenar "" a un numero en javascript.?

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo una funcion para convertir de binario a decimal y necesitaba cortar el numero introducido, y consegui esta pregunta:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914216/how-do-i-separate-an-integer-into-separate-digits-in-an-array-in-javascript

En ella explican que si tienes un numero ejemplo

```
var numero = 123456;
```

Y aplicas split() para obtener 1,2,3,4,5,6

```
var numero2=numero.split("");
var numero3=numero.splt();
```

No funcionara.

Pero si concatenas "" con el numero:

```
var numero3=(""+numero);
var numero4=numero3.split("");
```

Devolvera 1,2,3,4,5,6

Por que esto funciona?

Comment: Falta indicar lo buscado/investigado sobre el tema. Referencia [ask].

Comment: @Rubén listo hermano

Comment: :)  está muy bien que hayas agregado la fuente que originó tu duda, pero lo a lo que se refiere [ask] sobre buscar/investigar es sobre la pregunta que se está realizando, que en este caso sería el buscar porque funciona el último bloque de código que agregaste.

Comment: @Rubén entiendo entiendo, ya lo publico

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Porque `split()` es una función exclusiva para datos de tipo String, y en tus primeros dos ejemplos la variable `numero` es un Integer, por lo que no funcionará lo que quieres hacer.

```
var numero = 123456; //Dato de tipo Integer
var numero2=numero.split(""); //Error porque numero es de tipo entero
var numero3=numero.split(); //Error porque numero es de tipo entero
```

En tu segundo ejemplo funciona porque cuando haces esta concatenación `""+numero` tu variable `numero3` se convierte en un String con valor `"123456"` es por eso es que al llamar `split()` no te manda error.

```
var numero3=(""+numero); // Aquí tu variable numero3 es String
var numero4=numero3.split(""); // Ok split()
```

Comment: Y otra forma valida de conversion que no sea string,? Ejemplo function(numero){ var string="numero" jajajaj que se yo

Comment: Puedes hacer otra variable `numero2 = numero.toString().split("")`

Comment: @Victor-Random Si lo que quieres es "convertir" a binario/octal/decimal/hexadecimal/cualquier otra base forzosamente debes utilizar un string. Recuerda que en memoria los números son números binarios no importando su base y lo que quieres lograr es mostrarlo al usuario con formato en base n. Lo que podrias hacer también serie ej. `(123).toString(base)` que convierte el número a cualquier base que le indiques.

Comment: @Gerardo, eso lo se, gracias jejejej, lo que queria hacer era encontrar esa funcion de manera manual por a sin decirlo

Answer (score 1):

**split()** es una función para trabajar con Strings.
Si tienes:

```
var numero = 123456;
```

Lo que tienes es un entero, pero al concatenar **""** + **123456**, lo que haces es concatenar con un String y convertir a String, que ahora si puedes cortar con **split()**

Puedes probar lo siguiente en la consola del navegador:

```
console.log( typeof( 123456 ));
console.log( typeof( "" + 123456 ));
console.log( typeof( 123456 + "" ));
```

El resultado será:

```
number
string
string
```